# why does "chrome" and "chromium" have to have the same icon in the title bar?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, titlebar

Its really weird when I start chrome first , chromium picks up chrome's icon.

[image]

If I start chrome first , chromium picks up chrome's icon.

[image]

note that when I close any of them , the running on displays it icon with no problem , it switches icon if need be .

could somebody explains why or how to get around it ?